# How to avoid the storing values without spacing in an array?

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-api

In my shell script I have wrote to store the values of a command in an array. It has two elements (712,710), but they are stored in the array as one element (without spacing).How do I avoid that?

My script:

```
 #! /bin/bash

GIT_API="https://XXXXXXXXXX.lk/api/v4"
GIT_TOKEN="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
GROUP_NAME="testdevops"

GROUP_ID=$(curl --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" -g "$GIT_API/groups?top_level_only=true&search=testdevops" | jq -r ".[] .id")
echo "${GROUP_ID}"

USER_ID_ARRAY=($(curl --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" "$GIT_API/groups/$GROUP_ID/members" | jq -r ".[] .id"))

USER_ACCESS_LEVEL_ARRAY=($(curl --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GIT_TOKEN" "$GIT_API/groups/$GROUP_ID/members" | jq -r ".[] .access_level"))    
         
echo ${USER_ID_ARRAY[*]}
         
echo ${USER_ACCESS_LEVEL_ARRAY[*]}

for (( c=0; c<${#USER_ACCESS_LEVEL_ARRAY[@]}; c++ ))
do    
        if [ ${USER_ACCESS_LEVEL_ARRAY[$c]} != 50 ]
        then
        NON_OWNER_USERS_ARRAY_ELEMENT_NO+=(${c})
        fi
done
    
echo ${NON_OWNER_USERS_ARRAY_ELEMENT_NO[*]}
    
for (( d=0; d<${#NON_OWNER_USERS_ARRAY_ELEMENT_NO[@]}; d++ ))
do
        NON_OWNER_USERS_ID_ARRAY+=${USER_ID_ARRAY[${NON_OWNER_USERS_ARRAY_ELEMENT_NO[$d]}]}
done

echo ${NON_OWNER_USERS_ID_ARRAY[0]}
```

Actual Output:

```
36 711 712 710
50 50 20 10
2 3
712710
```

Output Need:

```
36 711 712 710
50 50 20 10
2 3
712 710
```

The Scenario is this: Identify the users for given group name in the GitLab and remove them from the group.

Comment: This is a bash-specific thing (use of bash arrays), so I updated your tags. Git is completely irrelevant; gitlab and their API might be slightly relevant, so I left those tags in, but you might consider dropping them.

Comment: This may not be the whole problem (I don't do a lot with bash arrays), but: `NON_OWNER_USERS_ID_ARRAY+=${USER_ID_ARRAY[${NON_OWNER_USERS_ARRAY_ELEMENT_NO[$d]}]}` is missing parentheses and will not append to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add elements with (), access them with the @

as follows:

```sh
# declare
myArry=()

for(( d=0; d<2; d++ ))
do 
   # add element with ()
   myArray+=($d)
done

# access elemets with the @ operator
for value in "${myArray[@]}" 
do  
    echo "$value"
done

# or access the first element
echo ${myArray[0]}
```